# One main domain splitting traffic to two hosting services

Tags: .htaccess, redirect, subdomain

Long story short, I am looking to maintain the ability to link to files hosted somewhere on my (network solutions hosted) domain, while redirecting all traffic that goes to mysite.com / www.mysite.com to my squarespace or shopify hosted site.

This is difficult (hopefully not impossible) because they require that my root domain be pointed to their servers that are hosting their version of my site.

I would like to set up a way that I could still use my hosting from network solutions for images and other files under a subdomain like stuff.mysite.com or anywhere else really but I don't see a way to have both self hosting of content and pointing to squarespace etc.

I had the idea that having the squarespace site based off of a subdomain of the main site like welcome.mysite.com, while redirecting traffic (possibly using .htaccess) from mysite.com / www.mysite.com to that subdomain would allow me to still use and link content from a different subdomain like stuff.mysite.com

If anyone knows of a way to make this happen I would love to hear it.

If any of these options seem like they would work, It would be awesome if you could provide specifics on how to implement them.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

> would like to set up a way that I could still use my hosting from network solutions for images and other files under a subdomain like stuff.mysite.com

If you meant you want to serve static assets such as images, javascript, stylesheets etc., then I suggest you use a different domain name.

This is because, you should serve your static assets from a `cookie free domain`, meaning a domain that does not set any cookies on the client side. By doing this, you will significantly reduce the amount of data transported between the browser and the web server. Since these are static assets, cookies are useless anyway.

So, in summary, register for another domain such as `mysite-cdn.net`. Host your static assets on that site.

This is essentially the theory behind CDN (content delivery networks, such as Amazon CloudFront). Of course CDNs also account for geographic proximity to the client.

Comment: Thank you that was very helpful. I guess I was trying to work around getting another domain, but it looks like it would be a good idea. All the CDN's I'm finding seem to be geared for more bandwidth then what I would need (and want to pay for) at this point but I'll keep that in mind for the future. Thanks again.

Comment: You are welcome. BTW, you can emulate a CDN on your own setup. Just run the site serving static assets on a different domain name.